# Interfacing to a differential signal with isolation

Tags: differential

For diagnostics I need to monitor a differential data signal similar to RS485. For safety the signal need to be fully isolated. The thought that I had was to use a pair of opto isolators across the signal. In this fashion one opto will be active in one direction and the other opto will be active when the signal is in reverse. Then a micro will convert the stream to something legible. Assuming the opto won't load the signal and the optos are fast enough to react, will the setup work or am i missing something?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKaxnY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What protocol *is* the signal?

Comment: ARINC-429/629?  You should be able to find a receiver IC for that...

Comment: If you're already working with the protocol, you should have a source for the receivers, no?  Worse comes to worse, just pull one off a spare interface card...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has to be enough current through the LEDs to make the optos work.

A terminated RS485 driver might have a differential output voltage of 2V, so you would only have about 800uA through the LEDs, which is pretty low, especially if the baud rate is high.

Of course you can always add a proper receiver and use that to drive a digital isolator (opto, magnetic or capacitive), which will cost more and require a power supply but will work first time up to many megabaud. I know which one I would do.